# How to sort CTypedPtrList using qsort?

Tags: mfc

I converted CTypedPtrList to CArray of pointers to object.

For this I added below code.

```
typedef CTypedPtrList<CPtrList, CMyList*> CTagInfoList;

CMyInfoList* myList;

CArray<CMyList* ,CMyList*> arr;

,,

,,

POSITION pos = myList->GetHeadPosition();
while( pos != NULL ){

CMyList* pObj = (CMyList*)myList->GetNext(pos);

arr.Add(pObj);

}
```

How to call qsort using CArray of pointers to object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a CArray of a user defined type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244487/how-do-i-sort-a-carray-of-a-user-defined-type)

Comment: I've been programming with MFC for going on twenty years. I have almost never used a Microsoft container. Please consider moving to the [C++ Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) for your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
qsort(static_cast<void*>(&arr[0]), arr.GetSize(), sizeof(CMyList*), CompareFunction);
```

where CompareFunction is a static method:

```
// header:
static int CompareFunction(const void* a, const void* b);
// cpp

int CYourClass::CompareFunction(const void* a, const void* b)
{
CMyList* pA = static_cast<CMyList*>(a);
CMyList* pB = static_cast<CMyList*>(b);
return pA->Compare(*pB); // Compare is a comparision CMyList* criteria
}
```

Also, you take a look on qsort reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/